# How to pass socket to setTimeout and keep it open

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using NodeJS and using the

```
tls.connect(port, host, options, callback)
```

To get my socket to write to.  I pass it through a async.waterfall and the socket.writable property stays set to true and I can write to the socket throughout.  However, if I try to use it with setTimeout, it ends up being closed.  Is there a way to keep it open or is my syntax incorrect?

This is one of the calls in async waterfall:

```
function (sock, err, callback) {
   console.log(sock.writable); // this is true
   
   setTimeout(function(sock) {
        console.log(sock.writable); // this is false but I'd like it to be true so I can use it for more logic
   }, 3000, sock);
}
```

I've also tried

```
function (sock, err, callback) {
   console.log(sock.writable); // this is true
   var sockz = sock;  
   setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(sockz.writable); // this is false but I'd like it to be true so I can use it for more logic
   }, 3000);
}
```

and this

```
function (sock, err, callback) {
   console.log(sock.writable); // this is true
   
   setTimeout(function(sock) {
        console.log(sock.writable); // this is false but I'd like it to be true so I can use it for more logic
   }.bind(this, sock), 3000);
   // callback(null, sock);
}], function (err, sock) {
     console.log(sock.writable);
}
```

But all of them print false.  Is my syntax incorrect or does the socket automatically close in this scenario where I'm trying to get it to wait?

### Edit

Full async.waterfall:

```
            async.waterfall([
                // insert record into db
                function (acb) {
                    dbConn.query()
                        .insert(tableName, ["HOST", "SERVER_NAME", "DATE_CREATED"], [hostname, "test", currentTime])
                        .execute(function (err, result) {
                            if (err) {
                                componentStatus.database = false;
                                // pass the error down to run all the functions
                                acb(null, sockz, componentStatus, err);
                            } else {
                                componentStatus.resultId = result.id;
                                acb(null, sockz, componentStatus, null);
                            }
                        });
                },
                // read record back
                function (sockz, componentStatus, err, acb) {
                    if (componentStatus.resultId < 0) {
                        acb(null, sockz, componentStatus, err);
                    } else {
                        dbConn.query().select("ID").from(tableName).where("ID=?", [componentStatus.resultId]).execute(function (err, rows, cols) {
                            if (err) {
                                componentStatus.database = false;
                                acb(null, sockz, componentStatus, err);
                            } else {
                                acb(null, sockz, componentStatus, err);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                },
                // send message to rabbit
                function (sockz, componentStatus, err, acb) {
                    sendStatusMessage(currentTime, componentStatus.resultId, function (err1, result) {
                        if (err1) {
                            componentStatus.messaging = false;
                            var error = err + ", " + err1;
                            acb(null, sockz, componentStatus, error);
                        } else {
                console.log("rabbit timeout");
                console.log(sockz.writable);
                    setTimeout(function(sockz) {
                        console.log("In timeout");
                        console.log(sockz.writable);
                        
                    }.bind(this, sockz), 3000); // wait for 3s to check record was consumed
                        }
                    });
                }
            ], function (err, sockz, componentStatus, actualError) {
                console.log(sockz.writable);
            });
        }
    });
};

exports.sendStatusMessage = function(dateCreated, id, callback) {
    var notification = { "dateCreated": dateCreated, "id": id };
    _sendMsg("test.queue", notification, {"contentType": "application/json"}, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err, null);
        } else {
            callback(null, result);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You don't show any code that closes the socket.  If the socket is getting closed, then there is code somewhere else that you have not shared that is closing it.  We will need to see that code and how it is use in context with this in order to comment on why the socket gets closed.

Comment: @jfriend00 I don't have any code that closes it currently.  I'm building it out little by little.

Comment: Then show us what else is going on with this socket.  There has to be more code context than you are showing.  sockets don't just close themselves after a 3 second timer.  So, something else is going on.  Not much we can do to help until you show/describe what else is going on with this socket.

Comment: @jfriend00 that literally is it for that function.  I commented everything out.  I added code for after the async.waterfall.  The sock is writable in the last callback of async.waterfall if I don't have the setTimeout.  But with the setTimeout it is not writable even in the setTImeout function.

Comment: Please show us the entire code context exactly as it is executed, including opening the socket and all the `async.waterfall()` stuff.  Sockets don't close themselves without external influence.  So, either you're messing up with the asynchronous operations and are getting fooled about the timing of something or some other code or the other side of the connection is closing it.  We need to see MORE context in order to help you.  If you aren't going to show more context, then we may as well just close this question because there is nothing else we can do to help.

Comment: @jfriend00 ok i updated it

Comment: And, where is `sockz` declared and where is the socket opened in relation to the waterfall code?  And, what exactly are you connecting to with sockz?  Please think about disclosing more than enough code and explanation that we could recreate the problem you are having.  What code reads or writes to that socket?